# Add spacing between double borders at bottom of <ul> with <li> elements

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have two 1px (or 2px) seperated lines at the bottom of my `<ul>` list.

This is what I have so far.

## HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>here's one </li>
    <li>here's another one</li>
    <li>here's the last one</li>
</ul>​
```

## CSS

```
ul {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
ul li {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
​
```

## [See it on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tnevg/2/)

How can I get some spacing between the bottom borders (the red and black)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be adding padding to the bottom of the UL:

```
ul {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 10px; /* your desired spacing */
}
```

Your updated demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/tnevg/4/

Answer (score 1):

just add `padding-bottom` to your `ul`

```
ul {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code added  1 px after last red line:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tnevg/3/)

```
ul {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom:1px; /*added this line*/
}
ul li {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
ul li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;

}
```